# Keyboard mapping gone wrong

Tags: keyboard, numpad

I've got an old Acer Aspire V5 with touch screen. Recently, I broke the touch screen and got to unplug it, because of phantom spam click on the screen, in order to be able to deactivate the touch screen.

I then plugged everything back in, and since, I've got a weird problem: the key mapping of the keyboard is wrong. QWERTY touches are alright, but <kbd>u</kbd> => 4; <kbd>i</kbd> => 5, <kbd>o</kbd> => 6. Same thing happen from the second line. The real numeric keypad doesn't work.

I tried to uninstall the driver and reboot but it didn't fix the issue. I don't see any <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>any</kbd> that could enable/disable this feature:

[image]

Before re-installing Windows (8.1), is there any other thing I could try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Fn + F4.

**OR**

Fn + ScrLock.

**OR**

Fn + F11.

This happens when the Num Lock feature found on lots of laptops is activated.

It can vary depending on laptop make and model but it'll be something like that.

*Edit* - I also have heard that Alt + Numlock works on acer laptops. Try that.

Comment: Fn + F11 did the trick! Thanks a lot Niall Jones

Comment: No problem! Glad it worked for you

Comment: `Alt + Numlock` worked for me; thanks for the update!